# Bubble sort error with nested (high scores) list - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, bubble-sort

For my software major work I have to create a program. In summary, the high scores list needs to be sorted before it can be written to file. To do this, I am using a bubble sort and I can't use the inbuilt sort function. The text file that the data is being read from is stored in a nested list. The text file looks like this:

```
NameOne
10
NameTwo
15
NameThree
9
```

This is the bubble sort code I have but does not work:

```
b_not_sorted = True
while b_not_sorted:
    counter = 0
    b_not_sorted = False
    for counter in range(len(highest_scores) - 1):
        if highest_scores[counter] < highest_scores[counter + 1]:
            b_not_sorted = True
            highest_scores[counter], highest_scores[counter+1] = highest_scores[counter+1], highest_scores[counter]
        counter = counter + 1
```

I need the scores to be sorted from highest to lowest. Any help would be greatly appreciated and you will be credited appropriately in my program credits :). Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a `for` loop?

Comment: Yeah, I'm allowed to code the bubblesort in any way as long as it works really

Comment: I would use a `for` loop for your inner loop rather than a `while` loop. It saves you having to increment counter manually, _and_ it makes it more obvious what you're doing (iterating over the indices of highest_scores).

Comment: What would the conditions for the inner 'for' loop be? I understand the concept of the bubblesort but the actual source code is confusing me

Comment: Please see the following answers for clarification on the `for` loop: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8107369/1142167, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4171389

Comment: Thanks Joel - I've read the links and done a bit of research but still don't quite understand what the condition would be

Comment: `for counter in range(len(highest_scores) - 1):`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a hint:

Check how many times your outer `while` loop is running. It should be running more than once, correct? What will always happen that causes the loop to exit, no matter what?

Try going through the code line by line and seeing what happens at every point.

The statement `b_not_sorted = False` at the end of the outer loop results in the outer loop exiting after executing only once. You need to move that statement to another part of your code. Try changing the name of `b_not_sorted` to `I_still_need_to_go_through_the_list` in your head:

Obviously in the first line:

```
while I_still_need_to_go_through_the_list:
```

it should be True, since you haven't gone over the list at all. You don't know if it's in order or not.

and after the line:

```
if highest_scores[counter] < highest_scores[counter + 1]:
```

Of course then we still need to make another pass, since we just made a change to the list and need to make sure no further changes are needed.

But what if no changes are made? `I_still_need_to_go_through_the_list` should be `False` then. Hmmm. If we put `I_still_need_to_go_through_the_list = False` right *before* the `for` loop, then it will be `False` *unless* we make changes to the list, which is exactly what we want.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the while loop to continue looping through the whole program so that it doesn't just stop after one pass? Another hint please! (Or the answer, haha)

Comment: @jaz: What happens in the last line of the code you posted? You set `b_not_sorted` to `False`. What happens after that?

Comment: @JoelCornett the loop doesn't end if I move/delete b_not_sorted = False from where it is and I know that ends the sort, but I don't know what to insert before that to make the loop continue going through the scores. I've been fiddling around with the code all day and still no luck with it

Comment: @JoelCornett Right, of course! That would make sense. But it still doesn't actually sort the scores :( any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @jaz: The code you posted above works perfectly fine for me. What exactly is not working? What kind of output are you getting?

Comment: @JoelCornett The code I am using now is slightly different to the one that I have posted however it works now. Thanks for your help - you're credited in my project references :)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `b_not_sorted = False` right after the first iteration, but it shouldn't be there! The algorithm just stops before it finishes the sorting.

You should instead do `b_not_sorted = True` only `if highest_scores[counter] < highest_scores[counter + 1]`

---

Also, the swapping code can look much nicer in Python. Instead of using `temp_var` just do this:

```
highest_scores[counter], highest_scores[counter+1] = highest_scores[counter+1], highest_scores[counter]
```

Python style guide suggests that you shoudn't write `== True` or `== False` in `if` statements. Do it like this:

```
while b_not_sorted:
```

Comment: Thanks! I've implemented what you've said, however the while loop doesn't repeat through all of the scores and stops after one pass

Comment: @jaz Make sure you've moved `b_not_sorted = True` *inside* the `if`.

Comment: It is inside the 'if' statement?